# executing a method after several methods run

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public void SomeMethod1() { ... }
   public void SomeMethod2() { ... }
   public void SomeMethod3() { ... }

   private void SomeSpecialMethod(SomeParameter) { ... }
}
```

For the moment, I have each of the first 3 methods call `SomeSpecialMethod()` just before these method return. I'm going to add about 15 more methods that in the end all need to execute `SomeSpecialMethod()` and I'm wondering if there's a way to say *"when any of the methods in this class run, execute `SomeSpecialMethod()`"* without having to explicitly repeat the call at the end of every method and of course prevent `SomeSpecialMethod()` from calling itself infinitely.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for AOP - aspect oriented programming.

C# doesn't follow this paradigm, but you can mimic it. [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) is one option, but I'd go with Castle interceptors / DynamicProxy instead: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx

You will need to create an interceptor that wraps around your object and intercepts calls to it. At runtime, Castle will make this interceptor either extend your concrete class or implement a common interface - this means you'll be able to inject the interceptor into any piece of code that targets `SomeClass`.
Your code would look something like this:

```
public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       invocation.Proceed();
       //add your "post execution" calls on the invocation's target
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Introduction to AOP with Castle: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx

Interceptors, and AOP in general, are usually used for things such as logging the result of every method call of an object, or logging every exception thrown by any method.

If the logic inside `SomeSpecialMethod` is abstract and not really related to `SomeClass` (like logging, for example), it might make sense to move the logic to the interceptor itself - but that's up to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; I didn't know about AOP. I'm going to leave my code pattern as is for now but I'll keep your answer in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I once faced such a problem and solved it like this: declared an auxuliary nested class (say, `X`) without any fields/methods, only with a constructor that takes an object of `SomeClass` and calls its `SomeSpecialMethod()`. Then made all `SomeClass`'s methods return that `X`:

```
public X SomeMethod1() { 
     ... 
     return new X(this);
}
```

Of course, there is an overhead, and you can do this with non-`void` methods (well, you can, but it'll get ugly).

Comment: What's the advantage of this over calling the event every method? Both require one line (provided you add the handler in the constructor).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Self-documentation, I guess? This `X` class could be named `GuaranteedToCallSomeSpecialMethodOnReturn`.